# Selenium/standalone-firefox docker on raspberry pi not working: how to use RSelenium on a raspberryPi

Tags: r, selenium, docker, raspberry-pi, rselenium

I am trying to use `RSelenium` on a raspberry pi 3 B+. I managed to get R and RSelenium installed.

I first tried to use `rsDriver(browser = "firefox")`, but I did not manage to get it work (it ends up with an error saying Could not open firefox browser).

As it is recommended to use `RSelenium` with docker, I am trying to get docker run a Selenium/firefox standalone container.

I managed to get docker up and running. The hello-world run works, as well as an ubuntu bash (`docker run -it ubuntu bash` gets me an ubuntu terminal).

I pulled a standalone-firefox image with a given version (the 3)

here are the images I have:

```
ubuntu                        latest              f576a39bda44        2 weeks ago         46.7MB
selenium/standalone-firefox   3                   d803a00f9219        3 weeks ago         756MB
hello-world                   latest              618e43431df9        10 months ago       1.64kB
```

I then do

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:3
```

But there is no container when I do `docker ps`, and

```
sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
351866263f7b        selenium/standalone-firefox:3   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   10 seconds ago      Exited (1) 6 seconds ago                        fervent_noether
```

shows that the container exited directly when executed. I tried with `standalone-firefox:2.53.0` (pulling and executing), and it resulted in the same problem. What I am doing wrong ? The version of standalone-firefox is not supported by the raspberry pi ?

More generally, does someone know how to get `RSelenium` working on a raspberry pi (with firefox as browser)?

---

### Edit

Following LinPy answer, I tried pulling docker images of selenium browsers compatible with the raspberry pi arm architecture. I found these:

- https://hub.docker.com/u/kynetiv/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/deinchristian/rpi-selenium-node-firefox
- https://hub.docker.com/u/pun4drunk/

The docker containers ran without problem, but I never manager to have the remoteDriver connected to the broswer in `RSelenium` (different errors for different reasons, I do not detail here).

The only way I found to use RSelenium on the raspberry-pi without distant server was to execute the java selenium standalone server you can find [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) (I tried the 2.53.0):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
```

And then connect to it in R:

```
library(RSelenium)
rmDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4444L)
rmDr$open()
```

It was that easy in the end.

Comment: and what in `docker logs  351866263f7b`

Comment: `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a missmatch between your app and the os ARCH . Actually it seems like application build for amd64, but you try start it on arm.

so check your Docker / APP versions and make sure they are compatible....

see [this](https://github.com/emqx/emqx-docker/issues/108) and [this](https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/issues/519)

Comment: Thank you for the tipp, I will have a look tonight

Comment: Yes you were right. I found armfh images, and they work. I didn not manage to connect the webdriver with `RSelenium` though.

Answer (score 0):

You used the docker container incorrectly. You actually can see your container doing docker ps -a, but it is not good. You specified -p argument and didn't pass any port to that, and you passed the image without a tag. Follow the official documentation for this image and try again step by step:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Comment: Sorry I mistyped when copying. I did passed a port, see my edit. I did as specified in RSelenium documentation : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/docker.html, and the same commands worked perfectly on my windows laptop. I redid following the commend specified in the github, and it did not changed the results

Comment: In the edit you added on you map the port 444 to 4445 . Are you sure ? Try this : sudo docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0, then sudo docker ps. You have to do this because the docker exports port 4444

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, I did 4444. See my edits, I tried with a new image